# Silverlight Submit Operation Failed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a strange error on silverlight business application, my project work on local network
i published the silverlight project on IIS, when i start the server the client user should access to the project and work, the client access to the project but he can't update the entity and get error "Submit Operation Failed"

The strange issue, when i update the entity from the server machine (Ex. Add new record) ,all client machines work (add-edit-delete), but only in case of i add firstly new record from server.

this issue make me confused, and i cant figure it.
please help me to solve this project because it happen in product version.

Project environment is (Windows 7 - IIS7 - SQL Server Express 2012)

Thanks

Comment: Is you connection string to the database using NT Auth or SQL Auth? If NT Auth, are you using impersonation? If so, did you setup security to database properly? Also, could you explain the second paragraph better. I think this holds the key to resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links to Help

[primary key issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04e29f22-0e32-41b2-af57-255d90cfff4a/submit-operation-failed)

[Sumbit operation failed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/7d806a62-db87-4630-aa19-b3ae4e4277af/ria-services-contextsubmitchanges-error-submit-operation-failed)

I guess it might be due to some key issues try using primary key and if possible on sql server try using auto increment primary keys. In case if any primary key is defined then insertion of records should have a unique key. Take a look and let me know

Comment: Anobikm, thanks for replay, all the tables in database have PK and it is auto increment.

Comment: The problem occurs when you add a new record after the first one ? Maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226671/silverlight-ria-poco-submitoperationfailed-when-inserting-two-new-child-ent

Comment: no no, the problem occurs in client machine when add a new record, but when add a new record from server before add from client the problem disappear.

Comment: it seems like the client can't open connection, but after server do, it work, or something like that.

Comment: this is pretty strange . Here's a same problem see if it helps http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/25eaceef-d4fd-4b74-8b0d-2248b69bb05c/domainoperationexception-submit-operation-failed